# Unable to send parameters while consuming a webmethod from a content editor web part using jQuery Ajax

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, content-editor-web-part, ajax, application-pages

I have added the code inside a `Content Editor WP` to consume a  [webmethod] that is written in the application inside a VS 2013 sharepoint 2013 project.

```
<input onclick="callWebServiceMethodAjaxTest()" type="button" value="Test"/>
<script src="/sites/Workflow/Style%20Library/VGBranding/JS/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/sites/Workflow/Style%20Library/VGBranding/JS/Json.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
             var methodUrl = 
          "http://srvr1:2020/sites/Workflow/_layouts/
             15/WebMethodProject/VGAppPage.aspx/GetProjectitemCount";
            var $j=jQuery.noConflict();
             $j(document).ready(function () {  
            ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadConstants, "sp.js"); });

            function loadConstants() {
            var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            this.site = ctx.get_site();
             ctx.load(this.site );
            this.web = ctx.get_web();
           var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('VGWebMethodSPList');
           ctx.load(this.web);
           ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccess),           
             Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFail));
             }

function onSuccess(sender, args) {

   IPC_siteUrl = this.site.get_url();
alert(IPC_siteUrl );
   IPC_siteId = this.site.get_id();
alert(IPC_siteId );
}
function onFail(sender, args) {
    console.log(args.get_message());
}
 function callWebServiceMethodAjaxTest() {
$j.ajax({
                type: "GET",   
                               cache: false,
                url: methodUrl,
                contentType: "application/json",   
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function () { },
                complete: function () { },
                error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result.d);
                }
            });
          }
        </script> ​​
```